# "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" never shuts up

Tags: python

I am trying to make a video game, but the program keeps shooting errors. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

My code below:

```
#code that keeps shooting error
for elem in(len(enemyList)):
#I keep putting global in here, but it never works
enemyList = []
...
def wave_call():
    if wave == 1:
        global enemyList
        enemyX = []
        enemyY = []
        for elem in range(len(enemyX)):
            enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 1500))
            enemyY.append(random.randint(0,750))
            enemyList.append("")
            screen.blit(enemy, (enemyX[elem], enemyY[elem]))
```

Comment: You need to show the traceback

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What line actually raises that type error, and what is the full traceback?

Comment: "Never shuts up" is not a good title for your question. It suggests you're just frustrated and not bothered to investigate the issue

Comment: The `len()` function returns an integer and as mentioned in the error message, it is not an iterable object.  Change your code to `for elem in enemyList:` or use `range` function

Answer (score 3):

On your first line : `for elem in(len(enemyList)):`. You forgot the range, it should be `for elem in range(len(enemyList)):`

Comment: Just to add to this, enemyList should be defined before using it in the loop:
Move enemyList = [] to the beginning, before the loop. Also it seems like you're trying to use enemyList as the total number of enemies before you decide to switch it to a list, make a variable called enemyCount and use it in your loop instead of enemyList.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the code for elem in(len(enemyList)): is causing an error is that you cannot iterate directly over an integer value (since you ask the program to iterate over a length).

in order to fix this, try using the range() function to iterate over it as follow:

```
for elem in range(len(enemyList))
```

this code will loop over the enemy list and allows you to use elem to acess the enemy.